# didSelectViewController does not work

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I added a tab bar controller programatically, and I want to switch view and hide tab bar controller with the method:

`-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

But it is not calling. I add delegate `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` and `[myTabBarController setDelegate:self];` in viewDidLoad.

What can I do? 
Thanks for your reply. Please help..

Comment: Which class implements the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol?

Comment: Which `viewDidLoad` method are you talking about? Which object is the tab bar controller's delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your app delegate's **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBarController.delegate = self;
```